# Next auth signIn failing error in aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth, aws-amplify-cli

I have deployed my next app on AWS Amplify[image] and Digital Ocean. However, aws amplify is always throwing me an error when I try logging into my application which uses the next auth signIn function. The same functionality works super fine on the Digital Ocean app but not working on AWS Amplify. I have tried everything but I am even not able to get the right access logs from AWS Amplify to understand the issue. The same code also works fine on local computers and digital ocean which makes me believe that this issue is from AWS amplify node versions only. Also, it is somewhere related to [next-auth][error][client-fetch-error].

If anyone is aware of this issue then please let me know.